# Variable is set to "0" but PHP-If function is displaying them anyway

Tags: php

Saturday and Sunday are set to "0" since they DJ won't be on the air. However in my function below, it displays them anyway.

`$djday = date( 'D' );` its set to return `Mon`, `Tue`, `Wed`, `Thu`, `Fri`, `Sat`, `Sun`

How could `0 == Sat` make the image display (return true)?

EDIT: Here is the entire script https://github.com/gregrickaby/DJ-Rotator-for-WordPress/blob/master/dj-rotator-for-wordpress.php

```
function djwp_image() {
        global $djwp_settings, $djwp_images;

        // set the timezone
        if(function_exists( 'date_default_timezone_set' ))
            date_default_timezone_set($djwp_settings['time_zone']); 

        // get current server time
        $djday = date( 'D' );
        $djnow = date( 'h:i' ); 

            foreach((array)$djwp_images as $image => $data) {

                if
                ($data['monday'] == $djday || $data['tuesday'] == $djday || $data['wednesday'] == $djday ||
                 $data['thursday'] == $djday || $data['friday'] == $djday || $data['saturday'] == $djday ||
                  $data['sunday'] == $djday && $data['start_time'] <= $djnow && $data['end_time'] >= $djnow)

                echo "\t\t\t" .'<a href="'.$data['image_links_to'].'"><img class="'.$djwp_settings['image_class'].' '.$data['id'].'" src="'.$data['file_url'].'" width="'.$djwp_settings['img_width'].'" height="'.$djwp_settings['img_height'].'" alt="'.$data['desc'].'" title="'.$data['desc'].'" /></a>' . "\n"; 

            }
    }
```

Comment: What variable(s) do you have set to 0? `$data['saturday']` and `$data['sunday']` or the start and end times?

Comment: $data['saturday'] and $data['sunday'] (or any day of the week not checked in my options panel will) return "0".

Comment: So is a day they are playing set to something like `$data['monday'] = 'Mon'` then? Also, you should probably group all of the `||`s because I don't think this going to do what you want with the time checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know whether the 0's you have stored are actual numbers or strings. If they're strings, then all the comparisons will be false, because the two strings aren't equal AND one isn't a numeric string.

However if the 0 is actually a number, not a string, then the string "Sat" is getting converted to a number automatically. Since it isn't a number, it becomes 0, and the comparison is true.

If you want to avoid all this type coercion stuff use `===` instead of `==`. But then you have to make sure all the types match up when you expect an equality to be true.

Comment: I just thought of this too (===) and tried:   `if
   ($data['monday'] === $djday || $data['tuesday'] === $djday ||
     $data['wednesday'] === $djday || $data['wednesday'] === $djday ||
       $data['thursday'] === $djday || $data['friday'] === $djday ||
      $data['saturday'] === $djday || $data['sunday'] === $djday &&
        $data['start_time'] <= $djnow && $data['end_time'] >= $djnow)` without success :(

Comment: @Greg do a `var_dump($data);` and it will tell you the types of everything.

Comment: ["monday"]=> string(3) "Mon" ["tuesday"]=> string(3) "Tue" ["wednesday"]=> string(3) "Wed" ["thursday"]=> string(3) "Thu" ["friday"]=> string(3) "Fri" ["saturday"]=> string(1) "0" ["sunday"]=> string(1) "0" ["start_time"]=> string(5) "06:00" ["end_time"]=> string(5) "10:00"

Comment: Just to be sure... this is specifically failing on weekends, and not just today? Because today is Friday... so $djday will say "Fri"

Comment: It's failing today. yes $djday says Fri

Comment: So, is that the answer? Should it not be showing the images today but it is, or vice versa, or, will it also fail tomorrow?

Comment: Here is the entire script: https://github.com/gregrickaby/DJ-Rotator-for-WordPress/blob/master/dj-rotator-for-wordpress.php

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5139/discussion-between-greg-and-tesserex)

Answer (score 1):

Is it the boolean/int `0 == TRUE` or the string `'0' == TRUE`?

Check the [PHP type comparison table](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) for more information about comparing these values. However, I think that you must be mistaken, "0" or 0 will never be a truthy value.

Comment: when I echo $data['saturday'] it returns a 0

Comment: @Greg: You'll want to use `var_export()` or `var_dump()` or a related function; `echo` will convert whatever you have to string, and information (that you *need*) is lost during that conversion.

Comment: ["monday"]=> string(3) "Mon" ["tuesday"]=> string(3) "Tue" ["wednesday"]=> string(3) "Wed" ["thursday"]=> string(3) "Thu" ["friday"]=> string(3) "Fri" ["saturday"]=> string(1) "0" ["sunday"]=> string(1) "0" ["start_time"]=> string(5) "06:00" ["end_time"]=> string(5) "10:00"

Answer (score 0):

With all of the OR statements, only one of them has to hit for it to pass that IF statement. I'm not sure of how your array is set up, is it something like this:

```
$djwp_images = array( '<image name>' => 
  array('monday' => "Mon",
    'tuesday' => "Tue",
...
    'sunday' => 0,
...
```

If that's how it's set up, then the if statement won't catch it because tuesday and monday are set regardless of if sunday or saturday are set too. I'm unsure without more data though. Maybe it would be better to set a ['day'], but I'm unsure what is already set up.

EDIT: and the others are correct 0 == "a"... You might need to use === for type checking and comparison.